# I keep slightly missing focus in Live View. Is there a way to recalibrate it so it matches viewfinder focus?

Tags: focus

[I have a Nikon D5600, but I'm sure any answers and talking points will be relevant to other brands too.]

When using Live View to focus, I've noticed that I often slightly miss focus.  I've heard the common wisdom that says one should use the viewfinder to focus, but that simply isn't an option for me.  I had my eyes lasered 21 years ago, but since then my nearsightedness has come back, to the point where even if I crank that little knob next to the viewfinder as far as it will go, I still can't clearly see the subject.   This is particularly bad for astrophotography as it results in thin reddish halos around the brighter stars; though in the LV monitor the focus seemed to be pinpoint sharp.

Is there a way to calibrate the viewfinder and LV focus settings so they match?  (If so, I'll probably have to get someone less nearsighted to help me do this.)

Comment: Are you focusing manually? Using AF? Either way, what lens are you using? If it's a 'Focus-by-wire' lens, that may be the nearest "step" of the focusing motor.

Comment: Manual focus, which is  the only way for astro. I'm not using any extra appurtenances or peripheral equipment to operate the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Live view shows the image captured by the taking sensor, so it is as perfectly calibrated as possible.  The problem is live view shows the image using a fraction of the pixels the full image has.  So even though the displayed image looks sharp, the captured image may not be.

The solution is to [zoom the preview](https://imaging.nikon.com/support/digitutor/d3300/functions/liveview_magnify.html) when focusing.

Comment: Even zooming the preview to max doesn't always result in a 1:1 magnification. Most rear screens are low resolution (keep in mind that manufacturers advertise them as *xxx* dot screens, rather than *xxx* MP screens. They typically count each R, G, & B subpixel as a 'dot'! The LCD of the D5600 is only 345,600 pixels (1,036,800 dots). With no zoom, there are 70 image pixels being downsized to each pixel on the rear screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you are auto focusing using live view, focus should be correct. Be sure the area you are focusing on has sufficient contrast and enough light. Live view on Nikon bodies (my experience is with the D7000 and D500) focuses with the aperture set to the desired value which gets around spherical aberration focus issues with lenses.

If you are using a non-Nikon lens, some bodies won't correctly focus on particular third party lenses. On a D7000 body, one such lens I have would only properly focus if the lens is focusing from near to far. This happens using the optical viewfinder and has worse problems using live view. Using that same lens on a D500, it always focuses properly.

If you are manual focusing, it gets as good as your ability to manual focus. Be sure to use the live view zoom feature when manual focusing. At full view, it is difficult to achieve critical focusing.

Regarding the comment that the optical viewfinder (phase focusing) is a better method for focusing, there are pluses and minuses. Phase focus tends to be faster than contrast focusing which is used in live view. However, if your lens suffers from spherical aberration (SA), live view will work better. SA will cause a focus shift if the aperture is changed. Phase focusing will focus with the aperture wide open, then set the aperture to the desired value when the shot is taken. If you have a lens with bad SA, you will get out of focus shots. Live view on Nikon cameras I have used sets the aperture to the desired aperture during focusing which means you won't have focus shift due to SA. Unfortunately, one of my favorite lenses has bad SA which is problematic for distances under 5 metres.

About not having enough diopter adjustment range for the optical viewfinder, you can use an eyepiece correction lens ranging from -5 to +3 diopters. Nikon has the DK-20C correctors that work with the D5600 (see page 322 in your manual).